# How do you use a dynamic library with qt gui application?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, dylib

I think I've created a .dylib file using this line in Terminal

```
g++ -dynamiclib -o myLib.dylib myLib.cpp
```

I've created QT widget application in a separate location.

I've tried to find a solution on SO and elsewhere, but I can't figure out how to get my application to use the dylib file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `.pro` file, from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html), you can easily use the `LIBS` keyword and set properly the include paths.
As an example (from the documentation):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lmath
INCLUDEPATH = c:/msdev/include d:/stl/include
```

If you are using cmake, instead, you can use `target_include_libraries` and `target_link_libraries` to do almost the same.
See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-commands.7.html) for further details about the available commands.

If you are launching it from the command line, you can use `-I` and `-L` arguments to do that.
See the documentation of your compiler for further details.

And so on. How to do that mostly depends on the build process you decided to follow.